# Javascript .addEventListener "mouseenter" for a class

Tags: javascript, html

first time poster, long time lurker here.
I have a table in HTML that has the ID SalesList and I want the cells within it to be highlighted green when the mouse is over it. The following code works:

```
var theParent = document.querySelector("#SalesList");
theParent.addEventListener("click", doSomething, false);

function doSomething(e) {
    if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

I found this code at https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm

My problem is that when I change

```
theParent.addEventListener("click", doSomething, false);
```

to

```
theParent.addEventListener("mouseenter", doSomething, false);
```

it does not do what I want it to.
I have also tried onmouseenter and many other event types and "click" seems to be the only one working.

Comment: The `mouseenter` event doesn't bubble, so the `e.target` will always be the same as the `e.currentTarget`, and will only fire when entering the actual element to which it was bound.

Comment: You can use `mouseover` instead to get bubbling. Don't know if that's the best solution or not without seeing your markup.

Comment: Also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34007612/how-to-change-link-color-when-using-jquery-mouseover/34007656#34007656

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do not use JavaScript for that. This can and should be used with css instead. Simply apply the `:hover` pseudoselector.

```css
td:hover {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<table id="sales-list">
  <tr>
    <td>Pineapple</td>
    <td>$3.00 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Bread</td>
     <td>$2.00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Let's compare this to what we'd have to do in JavaScript.

```js
var cells = document.querySelectorAll("td");

for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        this.style.color = "green";
    });
    cells[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
        this.style.color = "black";
    });
}
```

```html
<table id="sales-list">
  <tr>
    <td>Pineapple</td>
    <td>Bread </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>$3.00</td>
     <td>$2.00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In JavaScript, you'd have to query a list of `td` elements, loop through all of them and for each of them add two event listeners. This is about 10 lines of extra code we don't need.

TLDR: Best to use CSS for this.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I just jumped to the conclusion it would need js. I guess i need to focus a little more on [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Answer (score 2):

The onmouseover event occurs when the mouse pointer is moved onto an element, or onto one of its children.

The onmouseenter event occurs when the mouse pointer is moved onto an element.

So,
change this :

```
theParent.addEventListener("mouseenter", doSomething, false);
```

to :

```
theParent.addEventListener("mouseover", doSomething, false);
```