# Changing the color of the cells of a table on mouseclick using html

Tags: javascript, css, html

I designed a 2*4 table using html.I need to change the background color of a cell from white(default) to green on the odd mouse clicks and vice versa on the even clicks.But despite of clicking any cell only the first cell changes from white to green and vice versa.Kindly help me.Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change(){
        var s=document.getElementById('slot');
        if(s.bgColor.match("white")){
            s.bgColor="green";
        }
        else{
            s.bgColor="white";
        }    
    }    
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered a similar question here

[Javascript .addEventListener "mouseenter" for a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37911631/javascript-addeventlistener-mouseenter-for-a-class/37911691#37911691)

The difference is that this involves the `click` event and there is no css pseudo selector for this.

First query a list of all our `td` elements with `querySelectorAll`.

Next loop through and add the `click event` listener for each of them.

The class can be set multiple ways, but I recommend with the `className` method. To toggle between classes, the ternary operator is our best friend.

```
this.className = this.className == "white" ? "green": "white";
```

What this means is that it sets the class depending on its current value.

```js
var cells = document.querySelectorAll("td");

for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
       this.className= this.className == "white" ? "green" : "white";
    });
}
```

```css
.green { background: green; color: white; }
.white { background: white; color: black; }

#sales-list { border: 1px solid black; }
td { padding: 10px; border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<table id="sales-list">
  <tr>
    <td class="white">Row 1 Col 1</td>
    <td class="white">Row 1 Col 2</td>
    <td class="white">Row 1 Col 3</td>
    <td class="white">Row 1 Col 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="white">Row 2 Col 1</td>
     <td class="white">Row 2 Col 2</td>
     <td class="white">Row 2 Col 3</td>
     <td class="white">Row 2 Col 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```